# Django - Selenium - How to brake connection after one iteration of task?

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have simple Django app with integrated Selenium webscraping.
Purpose of app - to fetch images from Reddit and save URLs in database.
Task is performed in intervals.

My problem is following:
First iteration of webscraping task goes well, but all next are raising error.
I am assume that is because previous connection is not aborted.
I am using  driver.quit() command, but it doesn't seem to work, apparently

example of errors in console:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000289D7ADF8B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=62138): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/6a45df20c47126554c5ef365df554676/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000022678CE5D90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

scraping script:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from .models import Post
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

url2 = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/new/'
chrome_driver_path = 'C:/Dev/memescraper/memescraper/static/chromedriver'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument(" - incognito")

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=chrome_driver_path,
    options=chrome_options
    )

driver = webdriver

def fetch_reddit():
    driver.get(url2)
    meme = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[alt="Post image"]')
    memes = list()
    for m in meme:
        memes.append(m.get_attribute("src"))
        print(m.get_attribute("src"))

    driver.quit()

    for m in range(len(memes)):
        image = memes.pop(0)
        p = Post(image=image)
        p.save()

def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(fetch_reddit, 'interval', minutes=4)
    scheduler.start()
```